# mysql complex join with many tables with possible null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables in which data is being stored.

**DNS table** contains

```
tld(id) | 2ld(id) | 3ld(id) | IPAddress
101     | 33      | 3       | 203.11.1.19
```

(Example value)

I have **dnstld table** with

```
id(index) | value(char)
101       | 'com'
```

(Example value)

similarly **dns2ld, dns3ld**.

dns2ld contains, for example (33,'marriot') and dns3ld has (3,'australia').

I can join these tables with inner join easily

```
INNER JOIN dns2ld ON dns.2ld=dns2ld.id 
INNER JOIN dnstld ON dns.tld=dnstld.id 
INNER JOIN dns3ld ON dns.3ld=dns3ld.id
```

However I have **another table** which contains blacklisted domains which contains

```
id(uniq) | 3ld(char) | 2ld(char) | tld(char)
```

How do I join these 5 tables so I can list what is in the DNS table that matches a blacklist. Note in the blacklist 3ld may be NULL and 2ld may be NULL but tld CANNOT be null.

I might have many domains that in the blacklist but not in the dns table therefore not identified in the dnstld, dns2ld and dns3ld tables.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you probably don't need `Blacklist.id`.

Assuming you want to list things by hierarchy (ie if the 2nd level is not specified, the 3rd can't be either), I believe the following should work:

```
SELECT DNS.ipAddress, tld.value, 2ld.value, 3ld.value
FROM Blacklist bl
JOIN DNS 
  ON dns.tld = bl.tld
     AND ((dns.2ld IS NULL AND bl.2ld IS NULL)
          OR (dns.2ld = bl.2ld))
     AND ((dns.3ld IS NULL AND bl.3ld IS NULL)
          OR (dns.2ld IS NOT NULL AND dns.3ld = bl.3ld))
JOIN DnsTld tld
  ON tld.id = bl.tld
LEFT JOIN Dns2ld 2ld
       ON 2ld.id = bl.2ld
LEFT JOIN Dns3ld 3ld
       ON 3ld.id = bl.3ld
```

Umm, in the future, do you think you could not use abbreviations so much?

Comment: Sorry for the abbreviations. 

The condition dns.tld = bl.tld will not work.  As dns.tld is actually an integer (thats what I meant by id as index -sorry!) pointing to char value in the dnstld table.  Whereas teh blacklist table actually has the real char values in it. 

But I think I get your idea. Let me try a few tweaks and update the answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the entries in the dns table that *is* blacklisted, this query should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dns.IPAddress, dns3ld.value, dns2ld.value, dnstld.value
FROM dns
INNER JOIN dnstld ON dnstld.id = dns.tld
INNER JOIN dns2ld ON dns2ld.id = dns.2ld
INNER JOIN dns3ld ON dns3ld.id = dns.3ld
INNER JOIN blacklist bl
ON bl.tld = dnstld.value
   AND (bl.2ld IS NULL
        OR b1.2ld = dns2ld.value
           AND (bl.3ld IS NULL
                OR bl.3ld = dns3ld.value))
```

Comment: Thanks ! This query works right.  I just had a tweak it a little as the dns3ld value is sometimes empty in the database.  The query looks like 
SELECT DISTINCT dns.IPAddress, dns3ld.value, dns2ld.value, dnstld.value
FROM dns
INNER JOIN dnstld ON dnstld.id = dns.tld
INNER JOIN dns2ld ON dns2ld.id = dns.2ld
INNER JOIN dns3ld ON dns3ld.id = dns.3ld
INNER JOIN blacklist bl
ON bl.tld = dnstld.value
   AND (bl.2ld IS NULL
 OR bl.2ld = dns2ld.value OR bl.2ld = '')
           AND (bl.3ld IS NULL OR bl.3ld = ''
  OR bl.3ld = dns3ld.value);